# Dúvida sobre como o <header> é interpretado

Tags: html, html5, google, seo

Temos um `<header>` principal na página onde normalmente colocamos a imagem do logotipo.

Dentro deste `<header>` a imagem necessita tanto do `alt` como `title` para ser interpretado pelos buscadores correto?

Eu gostaria de saber se o buscador (Google no caso), vai interpretar o `<header>` lendo a propriedade `title` e assim associando-a.

Comment: Pelo que notei o Google também costuma usar textos próximos, porém não posso formular uma resposta com detalhes, pois o algorítmico do Google sempre evolui e pode mudar a maneira de agir, portanto não tem como formular uma resposta exata ou 100% correta. Acredito que o melhor seja usar no <img> alt e title indenticos. Nota: acredito que os buscadores geralmente se interessam pelo conteúdo da página e não pelo logotipo ou coisas do gênero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra responder rapidamente a sua pergunta, pela pesquisa que fiz, e como você verá a seguir, o que é utilizado para nomenclatura é o alt no caso da tag IMG.

Mas para uma resposta mais aprofundada, com a intenção de SEO funcional, se a sua intenção é ter sua logomarca vinculada ao seu website, o melhor a fazer é seguir os esquemas padrões que são adotados para esta finalidade, como schema.org que é conhecido como microdados (microformat / microdata).

Veja: http://schema.org/logo

Você pode "batizar" seu bloco onde está o logo como Organization:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/">Home</a>
  <img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" />
</div>
```

Uma forma atualizada do Schema.org é utilizar como tag SCRIPT, dentro do `<head>`:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
      "@context": "http://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "http://www.example.com/",
      "logo": "http://www.example.com/logo.png"
      }
</script>
```

Você pode também utilizar LocalBusiness com logo, como o exemplo a seguir:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <p itemprop="name">Nome da Empresa</p>
  <div>
    <img itemprop="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Nome da Empresa">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhm legal, bom eu estou com um livro de SEO "A Arte de SEO" para começar a ler.
Bacana você falar do schema.org, bem pensado! Eu já utilizei-o em meu site mas não dava tanta importância, apesar de que pelo google webmaster é muito legal ver que ele pega todas as "props" e "itemtype".
Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando, encontrei algo que possa lhe ajudar :

fonte: http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/seo-na-title-tag/

36 de 37 dos top SEOptimizers do mundo apontam que a title tag é o atributo mais importante para um bom rankeamento no google.

Para quem gosta de estatísticas, já encontramos um bom motivo pra cuidar muito bem das title tags.

Vamos ao que interessa: Agência Mestre!

8 dicas de SEO para fazer uma boa title tag:

1. Use o nome da página em todas title tag!

Mas mude o título de acordo com o conteúdo:

“Agência Mestre – Artigos”

“Agência Mestre – Black Hat”

“Agência Mestre – Link Building”

2. Não ultrapassar 60~70 caracteres.

Isso porque não vai aparecer mais do que 70 caracteres nos resultados de busca para o título de uma página…

3. Use palavras-chave (mas dentro de um contexto):

Atenção! Não vale keyword spamming! “mestre seo, dicas de seo, tudo sobre seo, tutorial de seo, black hat seo, meta description seo, …”

Use as palavras-chave mas com algum sentido: “Agência Mestre – Tudo sobre SEO” =)

4. Se for usar frases, que sejam relevantes

“Agência Mestre – 10 Motivos para não usar Black Hat” =)

“Agência Mestre – Bom dia, hoje eu acordei pensando em novas técnicas de SEO..” =(

5. Separador de frases: deixe a frase separada do resto do título

“Agência Mestre – Artigos | SEO na Title Tag”

6. O que a página oferece?

Um título para uma página deve seguir a sua oferta e procura. Quando a página oferece um browsing ou pesquisa, recomenda-se um título descritivo. Porém, quando se está vendendo ou oferecendo um download, deve-se deixar claro no título que a compra, download ou qualquer outra ação, pode ser feita no site. “Agência Mestre – Faça Download de e-Books sobre SEO”, ou “Agência Mestre – Pesquise os melhores livros de SEO”.

7. Mantenha um padrão

Estabeleça um padrão para o Título e siga-o.

“Agência Mestre – Artigos”

“Agência Mestre – Downloads”

=)

“Agência Mestre – Artigos”

“Faça downloads Agência Mestre”

“compre livros – dicas de seo”

8. Use o Título dentro da página

Repita o título da página na h1 da página, ou algo que o valha, assim o usuário vai ter certeza que chegou onde queria e que seu site oferece o que ele precisa. Para não falar que o buscador vai adorar encontrar no conteúdo da página o que a title tag diz que tem!

Comment: Outra fonte onde você poderá se informar melhor é no próprio Google:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=pt

Onde explica a interpretação das meta tags pelo Google.

Comment: O Title que foi referenciado na pergunta é o atributo da tag IMG e não o Meta Tag Title do HEAD do html.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir no seu header algumas informações que serão indexadas pelos buscadores, mas que não vão ser exibidas para o usuário.

Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Definindo Header</title>
 <style>
  header h1 {
   display: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Logo da Empresa X</h1>
  <img src="#" alt="Logo da Empresa X">
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Você define um cabeçalho de título para o logo apenas por questões de semântica, mas deixa ele com um display:none no css.